# Attempting to calculate total in views - displaying blank in template

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to calculate the total amount won for each user_name in the For loop and display it after Amount Won:. However, when I run the code below, nothing displays after Amount Won: - it's completely blank. I've even tried changing the player__user_name to = a single user_name and it still shows blank. Any help would be appreciated.

views.py

```
def index(request):
    latest_player_list = Player.objects.all().order_by('id')[:20]
    return render_to_response('stakeme/index.html', {'latest_player_list':     latest_player_list})
    total_amount_won = Stakes.objects.filter(player__user_name).aggregate(Sum('amount_won'))
    return total_amount_won
```

index.html

```
<h1> Players </h1>

{% if latest_player_list %}
<ul>
{% for player in latest_player_list %}
    <li><a href="/stakeme/{{ player.id }}/">{{ player.user_name }} </a><br>Total Won: {{ total_amount_won }}
</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<br>
{% else %}
    <p>No players are available.</p>
{% endif %}

<h3><a href="/stakeme/new/">New Player</a></h3>
```

I'm not sure if my calculation will even pick up each user_name in the For loop, but I'm not getting any information to work with with a completely blank result after Amount Won:

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two returns in your view function. The second one is never reached. Change it to:

```
def index(request):
    latest_player_list = Player.objects.all().order_by('id')[:20]
    total_amount_won = Stakes.objects.filter(player__user_name).aggregate(Sum('amount_won'))
    return render_to_response('stakeme/index.html', {
        'latest_player_list':     latest_player_list, 
        'total_amount_won': total_amount_won
     })
```

Comment: This seems to work! Thanks! If I change the total_amount_won line to read `total_amount_won = Stakes.objects.filter(player__user_name='test_username').aggregate(Sum('amount_won'))` it will display the total amount for that specific user name - for every user in the for loop. Do you have any advice for how to use each username for that specific place in the For loop? player.user_name and player__user_name both error "Player is not defined."   Thanks again!

Comment: It also displays the total_amount_won as `{'amount_won__sum': Decimal('4225.00')}` - I assume I can trim that - I will look in the docs and hopefully someone can lead me in the right direction

Comment: According to [Django documentation about annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) you can annotate the sum of Stakes directly to your Player queryset